# node.js "Answering questions" : broadcast out to the rest of the connected clients

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, real-time, javascript-framework

I'm trying to:

build a listening for the 'answer' event on the client, which will send us both the question and answer, which we want to broadcast out to the rest of the connected clients.

app.js =

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket.listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log("Client connected...");

    // listen for answers here

   client.on('question', function(question) {
       client.get('question_asked', function(asked) {
           if(!asked) {
               client.set('question_asked', true);
               client.broadcast.emit('question', question);
           }
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: I try:  client.on('answer', function(data){
    client.broadcast.emit("answer", data); 
  });

Comment: Where's the question? What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [hook.io](https://github.com/hookio) to talk to all the clients.  [This](https://github.com/hookio/hook.js) might be a good starting point.

Comment: oh, thx. but got it. in case anyone is looking, the solution is:   client.on('answer', function(a,b) {
      client.broadcast.emit("answer", a, b);
  });